# Using Tkinter after method to call a function that uses the get method is not working

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, get

I'm currently writing code for a Tkinter desktop app that tests your typing speed. I have a text box with random text and an entry widget where the user types in the words of the random text. After 60 seconds I want the entry widget to disable and then I use get to know what the user typed and compare it with the original text of the text box to see how many words were typed correctly to know how many words the user was able to type correctly in 60 seconds.

So basically what I wrote was:

```
def disable_entry():
    user_input = input_field.get()
    input_field.config(state="disabled")
    return user_input
```

...more code creating other widgets...

```
input_field = Entry(width = 70)
input_field.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

user_input = window.after(60000, disable_entry)
```

However, instead of getting what was actually typed in the entry widget with the get method, the user_input variable I create returns "after#1" the first time I run the program, "after#2" the second time I run it, and so on and so forth...

How can I fix this?

Comment: `.after()` returns an *ID* for the schedule task, not the return value of the function to be called.

Comment: Thank you for this input, this helped me cracking the solution. Instead of doing it outside of the function to be called (where there was no return value) I did all the actions inside of the function and it works.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue in your typing speed test app, update the disable_entry function to handle user input and add a compare_texts function to compare the typed text.

To fix the issue in your typing speed test app, modify the disable_entry function to directly handle the user input, and create a new function compare_texts for comparing the typed text.

```
def disable_entry():
    input_field.config(state="disabled")
    user_input = input_field.get()
    compare_texts(user_input)

# Other code...

input_field = Entry(width=70)
input_field.grid(column=1, row=1)

# disable_entry function will run in 60 seconds. Scheduled.
window.after(60000, disable_entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I understood from acw1668's answer that the .after() method returns an ID, I decided to do the whole process of checking how many words were correct inside of the function being called in the .after() method and it worked.

CODE OF THE SOLUTION:

```
#%% LIBRARIES

from tkinter import *
import random

#%% RANDOM WORDS LIST

word_list = [
    "scared",
    "adaptable",
    "children"
    "women",
    "mix",
    "button",
    "title",
    "eggnog",
    "observe",
    "bottle",
    "overwrought",
    "early",
    "comparison",
    "taste",
    "suck",
    "impolite",
    "barbarous",
    "fly",
    "drop",
    "spectacular",
    "greet",
    "please",
    "bee",
    "occur",
    "measly",
    "black",
    "reflect",
    "impossible",
    "proud",
    "zonked",
    "poison",
    "offend",
    "group",
    "punishment",
    "last",
    "cause",
    "white",
    "middle",
    "wink",
    "muscle",
    "letter",
    "rod",
    "illegal",
    "young",
    "railway",
    "water",
    "motion",
    "melodic",
    "tender",
    "exclusive",
    "ossified",
    "materialistic",
    "perform",
    "kindhearted",
    "responsible",
    "opposite",
    "house",
    "military",
    "small",
    "gratis",
    "moan",
    "elegant",
    "crack",
    "representative",
    "guess",
    "historical",
]

#%% CONSTANTS

YELLOW = "#f7f5dd"
FONT_NAME = "Courier"


#%% FUNCTION

def check_results():
    global random_sentence
    
    # Turn user input and random sentence into word lists to compare one against the other:
    
    user_input = input_field.get() #get what the user wrote
    input_field.config(state="disabled") #disable the entry widget
    nr_correct_words = 0 #initiate variable of correct words
    nr_incorrect_words = 0 #initiate variable of incorrect words
    incorrect_word_index_list = [] #where i will save index of word typed incorrectly to display later
    user_input_word_list = user_input.split() #create list of words user wrote
    random_sentence_word_list = random_sentence.split() #create list of words from the random sentence

    # Compare both:
    for n in range(0, len(user_input_word_list)):
        if user_input_word_list[n] == random_sentence_word_list[n]:
            nr_correct_words = nr_correct_words + 1
        else:
            nr_incorrect_words = nr_incorrect_words + 1
            incorrect_word_index_list.append(n)
            
    nr_total_words = nr_correct_words + nr_incorrect_words
    
    # Count nr of characters:
    nr_characters_written= 0
    
    for word in user_input_word_list:
        nr_characters_written = nr_characters_written + len(word)

    print(f"Your score: {nr_characters_written} CPM, {nr_correct_words} WPM! Out of the {nr_total_words} words you typed {nr_correct_words} were correct!")

    if nr_incorrect_words != 0:
        for index in incorrect_word_index_list:
            print(f"Instead of '{random_sentence_word_list[index]}', you typed '{user_input_word_list[index]}'.")

    
        
#%% CREATE RANDOM SENTENCE FOR USER TO WRITE

random_sentence = ""

word_count = 0

while word_count < 200: # I chose 200 because it's basically impossible for a person to write 200 words from this word list in 60 seconds
    random_sentence = random_sentence + random.choice(word_list) + " "
    word_count = word_count + 1
    
        
#%% UI SETUP

# Window:
    
window = Tk()
window.title("Typing Speed Test")
window.config(padx= 30, pady= 30, bg = YELLOW)

# TEXT:

text = Text(window, height=20, width=70, wrap=WORD)#wrap = WORD stop tkinter from going from one line to the next unless the word is finished
scroll = Scrollbar(window, orient="vertical") 
text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set) 
scroll.config(command=text.yview) 
scroll.grid(column = 2, row= 0, sticky=N+S+E)
text.insert(END, random_sentence) 
text.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

# Entries:
    
input_field = Entry(width = 70)
input_field.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
input_field.focus_set()

#%% PROGRAM CODE

# Disable entry field after 60 seconds and check results:

window.after(60000, check_results)

window.mainloop()
```